# issue tabel_exist in pyrocms

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, pyrocms

i am using pyrocms for my web application.
i want create library for my module in addons.
when i use this code for tabel llist in my database.

```
$CI = & get_instance();
$all=$CI->db->list_tables();
```

i have "defualt_products" value in `$all` array. this means i have "default_products" table in my database. but when i use next code , result is false. why?

```
if(!$CI->db->table_exists("default_products"))
    return false;
```

i use pyrocms 2.2.

Comment: no,still i have problem, i test this for all table that have not prefix, but those tables that start by 'default_' don't run correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dbprefix` method to include you table prefix from `database.php` config file:

```
if ( !$CI->db->table_exists($CI->db->dbprefix('products')) ){
   //there is no such table, products
   echo "there is no table named ".$CI->db->dbprefix('products');
   die();
}else{
   //table found
   echo "table found"; die();
}
```

In case it dose not work, then I think your problem is not this piece of code!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing anything to table_exists.  How is it supposed to know which table you are trying to check for?  It takes one parameter...the table name you are checking for.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/table_data.html

so, if you did this, and a table called "tablename" existed..then you would still get false, because table_exists returns TRUE if the table does exist.

```
if ($CI->db->table_exists('tablename')
{
return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: i am sorry. and thank from you lead. i correct my question. my code is correct, but i was not write question correctly.

Comment: Well if that table exists it would still return FALSE, because your expression is evaluating to TRUE.  You are saying "if this table exists, return false"...so it is working.  If you want it to return TRUE...change the return value to true...or negate the expression with a "!"... `if ( ! $CI->db->table_exists('default_products'))`